# Input text black in Chrome & IE, white / transparent in Firefox - WordPress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, firefox, input

Long story short, I had an app written in HTML / CSS and a little JS. It had a lot of input fields that were displaying perfectly in Chrome, IE and Firefox - white background, black text.

Then I've decided to integrate it into WordPress Page. And it works perfectly - well, until You open it in Firefox. In Chrome and IE, when it is opened as a page, everything works. In Firefox, the text is white / transparent, so it is invisible with white background...

I've browsed through few pages of Google Search on this but cannot find any resolution. Adding color: black; !important to input selector does nothing, adding style="black;" to any input field also. Any other solutions I have found do not work.

Do You have any idea how to fix this? It would be a shame to be closed to Firefox users and honestly it looks like magic to me, nothing is working...

So, after seeing comments, an example:

```
<input type="text" name="rozstaw" id="rozstaw" maxlength="4">
```

CSS:

```
div.eyes-tests-choose-glasses-modal #eyes-tests-choose-glasses-container input {
    font-family: Roboto, sans-serif
}
```

Although I don't really think this is the case - standalone it works great, on WordPress it does not. That's why I think maybe linking would be better way of describing things.

Comment: We are not going to guess what you have done. Post relevant code in a [mcve] - also look in the console

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to guess, but here are two shots in the dark that might help you out

First, try adding your CSS like this:

```
input, textarea {
   color:#000 !important;
}
```

Alternatively, you can do the same thing only specially targeting Firefox:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
input, textarea {
   color:#000 !important;
}
}
```

Comment: "Not all questions can or should be answered." https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer And this is one of them. Don't waste your time guessing what they did. It's often wrong and a waste of your time.

Comment: I know, but I kinda recognize this Wordpress problem, since this is something that Firefox does for both input fields and buttons, so this simple selector saved me a lot of hassle a long time ago.

Comment: Guys, I can provide a link to the actual website, maybe You will be able to find something. It's not that I don't want to paste code - it's just a long CSS and HTML code I guess noone would like to browse through.

Comment: Edit your main post and attach the link, you gotta have some sort of reference

Comment: @CodonPL If you can't create a minimal example, then SO is not the platform to ask the question, and a link to your site will not suffice.